# Match text between tags

Tags: regex

How do I match the text between tags when the end tag is non repeating?
Example:

```
DATA GOES HERE
aaa
DATA GOES HERE
bbb
```

The goal is to capture "aaa" and "bbb". I have tried the following regex however it fails to match the second batch;

```
^(DATA\sGOES\sHERE).*?\k<1>
```

The result from the above is always the first batch;

```
DATA GOES HERE
aaa
DATA GOES HERE
```

Thanks.

Comment: What are your *tags*? Could you provide your real life data?

Comment: @sp00m - The tags the text is between are headers. I search for key words to ensure I am at a header then want to grab the text between. I want to grab all text up to the next header, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a try with:

```
(?s)^(DATA GOES HERE\R)(.+?)(?=\1|\z)
```

The sring you want is in group 2.

Comment: Using your answer I am capturing the "DATA GOES HERE" but not getting the "aaa" and "bbb" parts.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the tag is always `DATA GOES HERE`:

```
(?<=DATA GOES HERE[\r\n]).+
```

Here is the output from RegexBuddy showing the match:

[image: match]

Explanation: -

- `(?<=DATA GOES HERE[\r\n])` - this is a positive lookbehind. It means 'make sure this is preceded by'.
- `.+` One or more of any characters (not newlines).

Essentially this looks for any sets of characters that are preceeded by a line with `DATA GOES HERE`. A lookbehind is zero length, so it does not participate in the matched text which is why you only get `aaa` and `bbb` which I am assuming is what you wanted.

**Update based on comment**

> It doesn't work if line-break is CRLF, also when there are multiple lines to catch

Quite correct about the CRLF, there should have been a `+` after `[\r\n]`. To match multiple lines you can use the following:

```
(?<=(DATA GOES HERE[\r\n]+)).[\s\S]+?(?=\1)|(?<=DATA GOES HERE[\r\n]+).[\s\S]+
```

The updates are:

- `[\s\S]+` Any characters including new lines.
- `|` = OR. Now it will match either between `DATA GOES HERE` blocks or for the last text after `DATA GOES HERE`.

Result:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work if line-break is CRLF, also when there are multiple lines to catch.

Comment: @M42 - yes, the CRLF was an ommission. Multilines - I have beefed the regex to handle this. See the update.

Comment: Yes, it's OK +1. But it's simpler to use the modifer `(?s)` that makes the dot matching newline.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, though (?s) makes it a bit tricky to not match the CRLF after DATA GOES HERE in the positive lookbehind. +1 to yours as well, the regex is definitely simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
(?:DATA GOES HERE\n(.+)(?=|$))+
```

to capture the texts between the tags (`aaa` and `bbb`).

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/fKqQl-K-fe7oID2k)